# Apply API policies using pipeline

Tags: azure, api, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-api-management

Greeting everyone!

I'm trying to deploy an external api to an APIM, however I'm not sure how I could deploy the policies xml file that I created.

I was thinking maybe this could be possible using CLI, however I can't find anything.

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this through the CLI yet. You can use a powershell script instead. Here I take it from inline xml but you can do a similar thing with a xml from your repo.

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
displayName: "Add API policy in APIM"
inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'YourSubscription'
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    Inline: |
    Install-Module Az.ApiManagement -Scope CurrentUser -Force
    Import-Module Az.ApiManagement -Force
    $PolicyString = "<policies>
        <inbound>
            <base />
            <authentication-certificate thumbprint=`"$(certificateThumbprint)`" />
        </inbound>
        <backend>
            <base />
        </backend>
        <outbound>
            <base />
        </outbound>
        <on-error>
            <base />
        </on-error>
    </policies>"
    $apimContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName $(apimResourceGroup) -ServiceName $(apimPortal)
    Set-AzApiManagementPolicy -Context $apimContext -ApiId $(apimRestApiId) -Policy $PolicyString
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```